# Send email with Png files in email

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I have 5 png images in a file which I want to attach to an email using Python. This is my current code. Images are names 1.png through to 5.png

```
import win32com.client as client
message_string = ''
message_string = message_string + 'This is my string'<br>

for i in range(1,5)
    message_string = message_string + f'<br><image src ="{i}"><br>'

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.To = 'testemail@test.com.au'
message.Subject = 'this is my test email'
message.HTMLBody = message_string
message.Send
```

everythings runs but the images do not load on the email. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The reason for doing it this way is because I am also including other data frames and this is the only logical way I could think of. Any other thoughts/ideas would be great

Comment: Have you checked the source of the resulting email? `<image>` is not even a valid HTML tag and your code certainly won't append a `.png` extension. Also where is it supposed to download the photos from?

Comment: i have created the images from matplotlib and saved them to the same directory. Also you are right, that was a typo in my code, it should read <img src= "{image}">

Comment: Same directory as what? The receiver doesn't have access to a directory that is on the server.

Comment: oh good call, so I have to attach them as well. That would explain the error

Answer (score -1):

Using the PILLOW Library would be helpful
`pip install Pillow`

### Something like this

```py
import win32com.client as client
from PIL import Image
message_string = ''
message_string = message_string + 'This is my string'<br>

for i in range(1,5):
    image = Image.open(i)
    message_string = message_string + f'<br><img src= {image} ><br>'

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.To = 'testemail@test.com.au'
message.Subject = 'this is my test email'
message.HTMLBody = message_string
message.Send
```

Comment: I tried and still just came up with no images